# Tailwind is not updating in real time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to create tailwind playground and i'm using CodeMirror and react-live package

when i write tailwind styles inside CodeMirror editor in source its there as renderers' class but not updating in real time. imagine you are giving style to div with text input its there but not changing anything. if i put pre-ready code in react-live livePreview it works just fine.

example video: "https://www.veed.io/view/c8676a90-367f-4be1-bb56-e134665af00f?sharingWidget=true&panel=share"

code fragment:

```
     function Compiler() {
      const [code, setCode] = useState(`
        function App() {
         return (
          <div>
           <h1 className="text-red-800">Hello, React!</h1>
         </div>
        );
       }`);

       const onChange = React.useCallback((value, viewUpdate) => {
        setCode(value);
      }, []);

  

      return (
        <div className="flex">
          <ReactCodeMirror
            value={code}
            height="400px"
            width="800px"
            theme="dark"
            extensions={[javascript({ jsx: true })]}
            onChange={onChange}
            basicSetup={{
              foldGutter: true,
              allowMultipleSelections: true,
            }}
          />
          <LiveProvider code={code} scope={{React}}>
            <LiveError />
            <LivePreview />
          </LiveProvider>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Comment: is the tailwind.config.ts configured propperly?

Comment: yes everything is fine i even added JIT

Comment: This is because tailwind doesn't include all the clases, only those that are used. Take a look at the [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names)